# SPSS mixed models - using classroom as an effect in the model

Tags: mixed-model, spss, random-effects-model

I'm looking at data from a health intervention study done in one middle school (16 classes/"clusters" at that school). Half assigned to control, half to intervention.

Is this an appropriate way to include the classes/clusters in the mixed model syntax in SPSS? I am unsure how to include this in the model. I have read that it would be a random effect, but I have also seen "schools" used as a fixed effect in others' models.

DV1 = my main dependent variable
Time = 4 time points
RandomizedGrp = 0 (intervention), 1 (control)
Class = coded 1-16 individual classes
(x) used in some places to denote multiplication

```
MIXED DV1 BY Time RandomizedGrp Class

  /CRITERIA=CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0, 
    ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0.000001, ABSOLUTE) 

  /FIXED=Time RandomizedGrp Class Time(x)Randomized Time(x)Randomized(x)Class  | SSTYPE(3) 

  /METHOD=ML 

  /PRINT=SOLUTION TESTCOV 

  /REPEATED=Time | SUBJECT(ID) COVTYPE(UN) 

  /EMMEANS=TABLES(Time) 

  /EMMEANS=TABLES(RandomizedGrp)

  /EMMEANS=TABLES(Time*RandomizedGrp)

   /EMMEANS=TABLES(Time*RandomizedGrp*Class).
```

Answer (score 0):

Are classes a (presumably random) sample of classes from a larger population, or all the classes of interest? If the former, typically class would be treated as a random effect. If the latter, typically it would be treated as a fixed effect (as in your MIXED command).